# API call to BigQuery.jobs.get failed with error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently using a sheet script to load data from sheets into BigQuery, however when I run the `dataUpload()` function I get the error below. I have correctly inserted the BQ project id, data id etc. and allowed the required permissions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. A more refined script will also be great.

> 8:41:10 AM    Error    GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to
> bigquery.jobs.get failed with error: Not found: Job
> big-query-test-xxxxxx:job_0vRPgne07b25coS7TBTuasdB6JSF dataUpload @
> Copy of Combined.gs:93 report_submission  @ Copy of Combined.gs:4

```
function dataUpload() {
   var projectId= 'big-query-test-xxxxxx'; // GCP project name
   var datasetId= 'test_data'; // Bigquery dataset name
   var tableId= 'Test_Test'; // Bigquery table name
   var lastColumn = 15; // Count of column (column A = 1)
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var select_sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   // get name of sheet 
   var select_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
   var lastRow = select_sheet.getLastRow();
   // var lastColumn = select_sheet.getLastColumn();
   if (lastRow < 2){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert("Empty!!");
      return ;
   }
   var range = select_sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
   let rows = range.getValues();
   // Normalize the headers (first row) to valid BigQuery column names.
   // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names
   rows[0] = rows[0].map((header) => {
      header = header.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]+/g, '_');
      if (header.match(/^\d/))
      header = '_' + header;
      return header;
   });
// Create the BigQuery load job config. For more information, see:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery
   let loadJob = {
      configuration: {
         load: {
           destinationTable: {
              projectId: projectId,
              datasetId: datasetId,
              tableId: tableId
           },
          skipLeadingRows: 1,
          writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
       }
     }
   };
// BigQuery load jobs can only load files, so we need to transform our
// rows (matrix of values) into a blob (file contents as string).
// For convenience, we convert the rows into a CSV data string.
// https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local
let csvRows = rows.map(values =>
// We use JSON.stringify() to add "quotes to strings",
// but leave numbers and booleans without quotes.
// If a string itself contains quotes ("), JSON escapes them with
// a backslash as \" but the CSV format expects them to be
// escaped as "", so we replace all the \" with "".
   values.map(value => JSON.stringify(value).replace(/\\"/g, '""'))
);
   let csvData = csvRows.map(values => values.join(',')).join('\n');
   let blob = Utilities.newBlob(csvData, 'application/octet-stream');
// Run the BigQuery load job.
   try {
      var result = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(loadJob, projectId, blob);
   } catch (e) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert(e);
      return e;
   }
   // Get job ID
   let json_result = JSON.parse(result);
   let job_id = json_result['jobReference']['jobId'];
   // Get job info
   var job_info = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId,job_id);
   let json_job_info = JSON.parse(job_info);
   // Loop for job Complete
   while (json_job_info['status']['state']=='RUNNING'){
      job_info = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId,job_id);
      json_job_info = JSON.parse(job_info);
   }
   // If job failed, alert error message
   if (json_job_info['status']['errors']){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert(JSON.stringify(json_job_info['status']['errors'][0]['message']));
   }
   // alert job complete message 
   else{
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert("Upload Complete");
   }
   Logger.log(
      'Load job started. Click here to check your jobs: ' +
      `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=${projectId}&page=jobs`
  );
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine for me. I did not encounter your error. Did you try manually comparing the `job_id` you got from the code versus the **job id** seen in the console or via command line and check if there is a difference? See [managing jobs in BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#list_jobs) for reference.

Comment: Also can you try specifying the `location` when doing `BigQuery.Jobs.get`. You can do this by `BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId,job_id, {location : 'us'}) // update the location if not in us`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'Did you try manually comparing the job_id you got from the code versus the job id seen in the console or via command line and check if there is a difference?'

Comment: I have changed my location and I still get the error